# configure jboss dashbuilder to use apache httpd authentication

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jboss

Situation: I have Apache httpd server and tomcat running on the same host.
Dashbuilder 6.1.0 Final was deployed as a tomcat app. I embedded the dashbuilder chart into a static web page and i am facing double authentication coming from Apache httpd(edited config to use ldap) first and then dashbuilder login.

I tried 
1: comment out the  section in web.xml
result: nothing would show in the http://serverip:8080/dashbuilder
2. Add tomcatAuthentication=false to AJP connector, doesn't work either
`<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" tomcatAuthentication="false" />`

What should I do to make user login only once (apache config) and be able to display the chart?

Comment: Are you connecting directly to Tomcat or do you use proxypass/mod_jk in yout apache httpd server?

Comment: i didn't connect them two. Thanks for asking though.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it work by changing the dashbuilder authentication to basic instead of form and then passing the credentials with http request in the web page. have to do it this way because the dashbuilder requires certain roles created and there is no way to map between these roles and the ldap group in apache config.